# How to Host many React-apps (with react-router-dom) in apache server without sub-domains?

Tags: reactjs, ubuntu, apache2, react-router-dom

I have an Ubuntu server with Apache2 where I need to host a React-router app among other web apps, (php, NodeJs).

The problem I'm facing is that I do not know how to tell react that the whole app is in a specific path, e.g., '/var/www/html/react_app_one/'

I changed the package.json to add the "homepage" attribute to '/react_app' and also changed the <Router basename={'/react_app'}> and  it seemed to work, when I type 'https://server/react_app/' in the browser, the app "works" but if I am in a route like 'https://server/react_app/users' and reload the page the server returns the 404 screen.

I also added an .htaccess in the public folder and made sure it was in the build:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /react_app/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /react_app/index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

But didn't worked.

In my "/etc/apache2/conf-enabled" there is a file that configures a reverse proxy for a NodeJS app, so I added the configuration in this file; in one of many tests, my react app worked but the other apps stopped working... I do not know what else to try...

Thank you in advance for any guidance.

Comment: You have to redirect 404 to the index.html in your apache config

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Thanks! That works: I added the line ErrorDocument 404 /react_app/index.html to my .htaccess and it seems to be working fine. My next Issue will be when I deploy a second react app in the same server... I'll struggle then.